# I want to use a random number to generate one of two cout's randomly

Tags: random, cout

I am trying to use a number randomly selected between 1 and 2 and use that to display a random cout. I can't quite get this to work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand(time(0));

for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
{
    int d1 = rand() % 2 + 1;
    cout << d1 << endl;

cout << endl;
system("pause");

if (d1 == "1");
{
    cout << "hello";
}

if (d1 == "2")
{
    cout << "goodbye";
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Did you ask the compiler to warn you about suspicious code? For example, "-Wall" for g++ or "/W4" for Visual C++...

Answer (score 1):

First i recommend you make sure that you are not comparing an int to a string. Also remove the semicolon from after the first if statement.

```
if (d1 == 1)
{

 cout << "hello";

}
```

Next make an else if statement instead of a new if statement.

```
 else if (d1 == 2)
{
cout << "goodbye";
}
```

This should fix just about everything. Hope this helps. Goobyebye!

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing an int to a string. change to, e.g. `d1 == 1`
That should get you going...

Answer (score 0):

When you make a statement like:

```
if (d1 == "1")
```

You are comparing a string and an integer. Try:

```
if(d1 == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the int to an int, then use the else clause.
Also, your if statement doesn't need a semicolon.

```
if (d1 == 1)
{
    cout << "hello";
}
else
{
    cout << "goodbye";
}
```